# Django queryset filter with if condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to apply a filter in django queryset only if a condition is met.
I have a filter object that contains forms list. if forms contains "all" then i want to fetch all objects of the AnswerDetails model else i want to fetch only the u_id in the forms list

Code:

```
fil = self.d.get('filter', None)   
f_uid = fil.get('forms',["all"])
if "all" in f_uid:
    f_uid = []
    a = AnswerDetails.objects.filter(proj=_p, 
        form__u_id__in=f_uid).order_by('-saved_on')
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what is the provlem with your code, does it result in an error?

Comment: when the forms list contains all, I am setting it to an empty list. Thus the result i am getting is empty but i want all the objects as the forms list filter contains all @AndreyBorzenko

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove form filtration:

```
a = AnswerDetails.objects.filter(proj=_p).order_by('-saved_on')
```

If you want to exclude something then you can also do this

```
a = AnswerDetails.objects.filter(proj=_p).exclude(form__u_id__in=f_uid).order_by('-saved_on')
```

Comment: I don't want to exclude the filter i only want to apply it if the filter list does not contains "all"